# Вызвать асинхронно один запрос из другого в MySQL

Tags: mysql

Привет народ.

Для разработки досталась база на `MySQL`. В триггерах к таблицам написано много функционала, что привело к соответствующему падению производительности.
Одним из решением было бы  выполнение данного функционала асинхронно. В `MS SQL` данная задача решается просто при помощи `Service Broker`. Таким образом, вопрос:

Реализован ли в `MySQL` функционал аналогичный функционалу `Service Broker в MS SQL`?

Answer (score 1):

Асинхронное выполнение запросов в mysql "из коробки" не доступно. Но пытливые умы решают эту проблему, используя нестандартные клиентские библиотеки( http://habrahabr.ru/post/155377/ или http://samag.ru/archive/article/2542) или используя странные механизмы типа этого - http://www.phphighload.com/2013/05/asynchronous-mysql-queries-with-xbox.html